# Session Variable List, when adding a new Object I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, class, session

Here is my Session Class

```
public static class Sessions
{

    public class UserSession
    {

        public string CurrentSelected
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Req
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public DateTime Reque
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<Options> Option;
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public string Te;
        public string Fe;
        public string Fg;
        public string DE;
    }

}
```

I create a new session of my class

```
    Session["SessionStats"] = new UserSession();
```

Then I try to add to the List

```
    foreach(string hello in helloworld) {
                Options RO = new Options();
                RO.DE = item.GetDataKeyValue("DE").ToString();
                RO.Fg = item.GetDataKeyValue("Fg").ToString();
                RO.Fe = item.GetDataKeyValue("Fe").ToString();
                RO.Te = item.GetDataKeyValue("Te").ToString();
    }
```

This is where the error occurs

```
((UserSession)Session["SessionStats"]).Options.Add(RO);
```

RO is correctly populated but `((UserSession)Session["SessionStats"]).Option` is null, I'm not sure how to add RO to this list.  This has to be a list because I have like 10 RO's I need to put in this list.

Comment: yeah i need a vacation public List<Options> Option = new new List<Options>();

Comment: I'd probably add that to the constructor for `UserSession`.

Comment: Your code, as it stands, is rather confusing: what is 'item' in the foreach-loop? Why is 'hello' not used in the foreach? Why are you referring to UserSession.Option in one place and UserSession.Options (note the added 's') in another?

Answer (score 0):

After

```
Session["SessionStats"] = new UserSession();
```

you have added a new `UserSession`, whose `Option` property is null, to `Session`. Then, when you do

```
((UserSession)Session["SessionStats"]).Options.Add(RO);
```

you are pulling out that very same object and accessing the `Option` property, which is null, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

It looks like you are forgetting to assign something to the newly created `UserOption`'s `Option` property. However, you don't seem to be using the `Options` you are instantiating in the `foreach` for anything...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 'Option' and 'Options'. Change the class name from 'Option' to 'Options'. Then change this line:

```
((UserSession)Session["SessionStats"]).Options.Add(RO);
```

to

```
((UserSession)Session["SessionStats"]).Option.Add(RO);
```